# authentication using identity server with existing database of membershipreboot

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4, membershipreboot

I have a Web application where I am using [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) to implement authentication. Now I want to use Identity server 4 (with MVC core)to secure this application and an API. I found that We can customize IResourceownerpasswordvalidator and
IProfileservice classes to use existing database with identity server. I also see there is membershipreboot [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot) with identity server 3 but not with identity server 4.

Please suggest what method do I need to use for user authentication using identity server with existing database of membershipreboot.

Comment: Youre going to find it very difficult especially if you were using MembershipReboot with EF 6.x.

Comment: so what is solution? can i treat membershipreboot db as custom db only or what ?